# Hide default browser scroll bar without overflow:hidden when using Perfect Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using "perfect scroll bar" on my web page. To hide the default browser scroll bars it adds "overflow:hidden". (http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/)

I'm also using Jquery Sortable in the scrollable section. (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)
The overflow hidden needed for perfect scroll is a barrier for sortable. When I drag a div it won't scroll down as needed because overflow is hidden. ( But when you scroll with the mouse wheel it will scroll ).

When I removed overflow:hidden the default scrollbar AND the perfect scroll bar shows. (Both of them work as expected)

So, how do I **visually hide the scrollbar** so that the overflow is not hidden but only the scrollbar is just not visible.

Comment: can you make a simple example on jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your entire page inside a div whose height and width are equal to that of the window and then apply the perfect scroll bar on that div.

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
  <!-- page content -->
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".body").css({
 "width": $(window).width() + "px",
 "height": $(window).height() + "px" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here, is that without using `overflow: hidden` you're not going to be able to hide the scrollbars.

While webkit browsers do support `::-webkit-scrollbar`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-button`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` and `::-webkit-resizer` in your CSS, targeting other browsers will be difficult.

A possible "hack" could be wrapping your content in a div with the same size as the window, applying PerfectScrollbars to said div, and placing your jQuery Sortable content inside a child div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="scroll">
       //Your all content
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scroll{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        $("#scroll").css({
        "width": $(window).width() + "px",
        "height": $(window).height() + "px" 
        });
    });
    const ps = new PerfectScrollbar('#scroll', {
        wheelSpeed: 2,
        wheelPropagation: true,
        minScrollbarLength: 20
    });
    ps.update();
```